# Solving a triangle, given two sides and the measure of the included angle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

Let say you have a triangle

Angle A = 41 degrees , side b = 3.41 and c = 5.83

can you use pythagoras theorem to find the side a?
and how can you find Angle B and C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to use the Pythagorean Theorem to find any of the unknown information about the triangle.  It is possible to use some right triangle trigonometry in combination with the Pythagorean Theorem to find the unknown information, but it's simpler to use the [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)—to find the unknown side and then to find the unknown angles.

Comment: Any small example?

Comment: @user1022734: Use $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A$ to find $a$, then use $\cos C=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$ to find $C$ and a similar equation to find $B$.

Comment: to find a i most do : b^2+c^ - 2 *b *cos(A) ? or

Comment: square root((((3,41^2) + (5,83^2)) - (2 * 3,41)) * 5,83) * cos(41 degree) = 11,3504535 ?

Comment: @user1022734: I think your parentheses are misplaced.  I've taken your expression and moved the parentheses, underlined things that are in parentheses together:  $$\text{sqrt}\underline{(\underline{(\underline{(3,41^2)} + \underline{(5,83^2)})} - \underline{(\underline{(\underline{(2 * 3,41)} * 5,83)} * \cos\underline{(41^\circ)})})}\approx 3.95086$$

Comment: But i'm getting :    ((3,95086^2) + (5,83^2) - (3,41^2)) / (2 * 3,95086 * 3,41) = 1,40917739  when Trying to find C ?

Comment: @user1022734: The last 3.41, just before the =, should be 5.83.

Comment: ((3.95086^2) + (3.41^2) - (5.83^2)) / (2 * 3.95086 * 3.41) = -0.250567416 , Now i get This as C is it correct?

Comment: @user1022734: That looks reasonable for the cosine of C—you'll have to use the inverse cosine (or arccosine) function to find the angle measure.

Comment: cos -1 ( C )  = 104.51109 , Thanks, What is the area formula? is it T = 1/2 * a* b* sin(C) ?

Comment: @user1022734: Yes.

Answer (score 2):

To find side $a$ use [Law Of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_law):

$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2\cdot b \cdot c \cos \alpha$$

To find angles $\beta$ and $\gamma$ use [Sine Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_law) :

$$\frac{a}{\sin \alpha} =\frac{b}{\sin \beta} = \frac{c}{\sin \gamma}$$

Comment: Unless you know that neither of the unknown angles is going to be obtuse, it's probably better to use the Law of Cosines to find the unknown angles to avoid the ambiguity using a sine to find an angle measure between 0° and 180°.